# Is the solution space of a homogeneous linear system the same as the null space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the solution space of a homogeneous linear system the same as the null space?

If not how do they differ?

(sorry if this is a really stupid question)

Comment: It is. $Ax = 0$ is equivalent to $x$ being in the null-space of $A$.

Comment: They are the same, if you mean null space of the matrix given by the coefficients

Comment: Depends on how many hairs you want to split: the solution space of a homogenous linear system is the null space of the associated matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty much correct, all I would do is to make a slight correction to your mathematical grammar. Given a homogeneous linear system of equations written as a matrix equation $MX=0$, the solution space of the system is the same as the null space **of the matrix $M$**.

Comment: Ah, makes perfect sense. Thank you!